# How to use sLineBreak from the object inspector?

Tags: string, delphi, designer, object-inspector

Currently, I'm setting a string which contains sLineBreak constant as value for the Caption property of a TLabel control.

```
MyLabel.Caption := 'A' + sLineBreak + 'B';
```

sLineBreak is defined in System.pas as follows (Delphi 2007):

```
const
      sLineBreak = {$IFDEF LINUX} #10 {$ENDIF} {$IFDEF MSWINDOWS} #13#10 {$ENDIF};
```

Is there a way to do the same thing by using the object inspector? (At design time).

**Update:**
Probably in future I will move this project to a newer IDE and will develop on different platforms, but at the moment there's no particular reason why I'm using sLineBreak instead of #13#10. I'm sorry for misunderstanding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use the `sLineBreak` constant at design-time.  However, you can either:

1. Edit the DFM directly (right-click the Form Designer and choose `View as Text`) to insert CR/LF characters into the encoded `Caption` text, eg:

   Using a bare-LF line break

   ```
   object MyLabel: TLabel
     Caption = 'A'#10'B'
   end
   ```

   Using a CRLF line break

   ```
   object MyLabel: TLabel
     Caption = 'A'#13#10'B'
   end
   ```
2. Install a third party design-time property editor (or write your own) that allows multi-line editing of `String` property values. For example, ["Extended String Property Editor"](http://delphidabbler.com/software/stringpe/main).

Comment: The only problem with both of your proposed solutions is that it doesn't use `sLineBreak`, but hard-codes in the Windows CR/LF pair.

Comment: @KenWhite the first solution allows you to choose which characters you want to use. The second solution uses whatever line break is used by `TStrings`, which is `sLineBreak` by default, but would be dependant on what `sLineBreak` is in the IDE's copy of the RTL, and since the IDE is a Windows app, that would be CRLF. But that is why I also mentioned writing your own property editor (which is not difficult to do), then you can use whatever characters you want.

Comment: Editing the DFM to insert CR/LF (or simply a LF) does not handle differentiating between platforms. The property editor probably would. (I've had issues with third-party replacements of the property editor for `String` that want to do far more than desired, and to me it's not worth while to avoid adding a single line of code in the constructor).

Comment: @KenWhite the OP is using D2007, so no cross-platform development, so `sLineBreak` is always CRLF

Comment: Sure. Until next week when it's upgraded to Seattle or Berlin. :-) Presumably the OP has a reason for using `sLineBreak` instead of `#13#10`.

Comment: The property editor will help with design time multi-line text entry, however it can't persist "sLineBreak" as it would prevent compilation.

Comment: VCL's `TLabel` accepts `bare-CR`, `bare-LF`, and `CRLF` as a line break.  FireMonkey's `TLabel` accepts `bare-LF` and `CRLF`, but not `bare-CR`.  So, just use `bare-LF` or `CRLF` in the DFM and you should be fine on all platforms.

Comment: Can you show an example of ow to use `bare-LF` in a DFM file that will work? I've never seen a DFM file that will accept compile-time variables.

Comment: @KenWhite see the example in my answer.

Comment: Got it. You mean *hard-code the LF or CRLF in the DFM*, rather than *instead of sLineBreak you can use bare-LF or CRLF*. Misunderstood what your comment meant.

Answer (score 5):

No, the Object Inspector doesn't evaluate variables at design time.

The usual way to work around this is to set the caption in the form's constructor:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MyLabel.Caption := 'A' + sLineBreak + 'B';
end;
```

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming that you wish to do this in a cross-platform setting, in which case it cannot be done. Form files do not have any mechanism for conditional value specification. You should apply the value at runtime.